# Trying to transpose a matrix in C using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

The rest of my code is right I believe but just the transpose part is wrong.

Here's the code for the transpose part:

```
void transpose(int *m1, int *m2, int n) {

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while(i=0, i<n) {
        while(j=0, j<n) {
            *(m1+i*n+j) = *(m2+j*n+i);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }


}
```

And here is the results:

```
M1=
  8  1  6
  3  5  7      //Original Matrix
  4  9  2 

M1'=
  8  3  4
  0  0  0             //Transpose matrix
  0  0-71503482
```

Does anyone know where I went wrong?

Comment: Use `for` loops; they're easier to understand and harder to get wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
while(i=0, i<n)
```

It should be:

```
for(i=0; i<n;)
```

And of course you can move the `i++` and the declaration in there too:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to elaborate a little bit on John's answer, because it's not clear
whether you understand what this code really does:

```
while(i=0, i<n)
```

Here you are using the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

I'd like to quote Wikipedia:

> [Wikipedia: Comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)
>
> [...] the comma operator (represented by the token ,) is a binary operator that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value (and type)

```
i=0, i<n
```

will set `i` to 0, then compare `i<n` and returns this evaluation as result.
Because `n` is 3, the condition is evaluated as true and the program enters the
loop. However, every time the condition for the `while` loop must be evaluated,
`i = 0, i<n` is executed, thus always setting `i` to 0 first. In fact you
created an endless loop.